# Why are ES6 template strings the way they are?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What are the reasons that we have to use:

1. `` ` `` instead of `'`, and
2. `${var}` instead of `$var` (like e.g. in Kotlin)

Comment: Unlike **Kotlin**, **PHP** etc. for which using double or single quotes changes how the string is interpreted, there is no difference in the two syntaxes in **ECMAScript**.  
A string using **double quotes** is exactly the same as a string using **single quotes**. 

And they had to do something that was backward compatible with the previous version of **ECMAScript**. So they introduced ``${variable}`` syntax

Comment: ${obj.prop} ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. backwards compatibility: you don't want existing programs using single quoted strings to suddenly behave differently because they are now interpreted as template strings.
2. Too often a dollar sign may need to be literal. To avoid that you would have to escape it often, `${  }` is prescribed: it is a less recurring pattern you would want to produce literally in strings.